# Export HTML table to Excel not downloading file using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, umbraco7

I'm creating an Umbraco website, and I am creating a plugin for the backend of Umbraco so a user can export an Excel worksheet from an HTML table.
I'm using AngularJS and a C# controller to do this. Here are my files.

```
//This is my C# Controller at /App_Code/ExportBlankDictionaryController.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Editors;
using Umbraco.Core.Persistence;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.IO;

namespace AngularUmbracoPackage.App_Code
{
    [Umbraco.Web.Mvc.PluginController("AngularUmbracoPackage")]
    public class ExportBlankDictionaryController : UmbracoAuthorizedJsonController
    {
        //[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        //[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public void ExportExcell()
        {
            var keys = new System.Data.DataTable("BlankDictionaryItems");
            keys.Columns.Add("Keys", typeof(string));
            keys.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));

            keys.Rows.Add("Enter First Dictionary Name Here", " ");

            var grid = new GridView();
            grid.DataSource = keys;
            grid.DataBind();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=BlankDictionaryItems.xls");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            grid.RenderControl(htw);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

```
// This is my AngularJS controller at /App_Plugins/datatable/datatable.controller.js:

angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("AngularUmbracoPackage.ExportBlankDictionaryController", function ($scope, keyResource) {
        keyResource.exportToExcell().then(function (response) {
            alert("Table Generated!");
        })
    });
```

This is my datatable.resource.js file within the same directory:

```
// Adds the resource to umbraco.resources module:
angular.module('umbraco.resources').factory('keyResource',
    function ($q, $http) {
        // The factory object returned
        return {
            // This calls the API controller we setup earlier
            exportToExcell: function () {
                console.log("button clicked");
                return $http.post("backoffice/AngularUmbracoPackage/ExportBlankDictionary/ExportExcell");
            }
        };
    }
);
```

If necessary, here is the package.manifest.json file:

```
{
    propertyEditors:[
    {
        name: "DataTable editor",
        alias: "my.datatable.editor",
        editor:{
            view: "~/app_plugins/datatable/table.html",
            valueType: "JSON"
        }
    }
    ],
    javascript: [
    "~/app_plugins/datatable/datatable.controller.js",
    "~/app_plugins/datatable/datatable.resource.js"
    ]
}
```

Here is the table.html file which is the view:

```
<div class="ExportDiv" ng-controller="AngularUmbracoPackage.ExportBlankDictionaryController">
    <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered" runat="server">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Key</th>
                <th>Populate Dictionary Item Names in Key Column</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter First Dictionary Name Here</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="exportToExcel()">Export Table</button>
```

Okay, so the Umbraco page is loading, the alert box comes up when the developer section of Backoffice is opened, but when I click the *Export Table* button, nothing happens. I am trying to get an Excel sheet to download when this button is clicked. How can I do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Which function does you `ng-click` refer to???? I don't see it in any scope. This button is also outside of any controller. Try `Console.log("button");` when you press it.

Comment: Updated the file sorry the ng-click should refer to exportToExcell() Still running the alert but not downloading the sheet.

Comment: I'm not referring to `alert("Table Generated!");`. Do you have some way to make sure that when you're pressing the button, angular calls a function? And which function is it (your button is outside of any ng-scope)

Comment: Okay so it's logging button clicked before the button has even been clicked. it's running the function exportToExcel on loading the page. This should not be happening.

Comment: It should *of course* be happening. Your line `keyResource.exportToExcell().then(function (response) {` is called during the instantiation of the angular controller (AngularUmbracoPackage.ExportBlankDictionaryController). You have done nothing to actually implement a function that is called on `ng-click` of the button.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
angular.module("umbraco")
    .controller("AngularUmbracoPackage.ButtonController", function ($scope, keyResource) {
        $scope.ButtonClickHandler = function(){
             console.log("clicked me!");
             keyResource.exportToExcell().then(function (response) {
             //do something with the response from the server
        }
    });
```

then change the button element to:

```
<button ng-controller="AngularUmbracoPackage.ButtonController" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="ButtonClickHandler()">Export Table</button>
```

Comment: Tried this but to no avail.Why are you calling the button controller? When the controller should be the C# controller? That's where the code to export the table is.This isn't even logging "clicked me!" to the console.

Comment: The angular controller, has nothing to do with ASP.NET's MVC controllers.

Comment: Try setting the debug to true in the web.config or your files will be bundled and cached

Comment: debug is set to true in Web.config. My problem is the controller isn't outputting anything. I fixed the angular controller, and the C# file is now being hit, the problem here is that my C# code isn't returning an excel file.

Comment: In your c# code, what are you trying to do? you're sending a string writer object as the body of your response, yet you haven't added anything to the string writer.

Comment: I'm trying to create a blank xls file, I've also tried CSV but it's just not doing anything at all.

Comment: Can you show me the C# code that creates the .xls file? I don't think that you are creating one, much less sending it as a response.

Comment: That is all I have. This is my entire point, I don't know enough C# to know what I'm doing with this. If you follow this link you'll see another method I tried: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641659/my-c-sharp-controller-isnt-downloading-a-csv-or-excel-file?noredirect=1#comment60878481_36641659

Comment: Don't try to copy paste code that you don't understand what it's doing. It will get you nowhere. Do you know Javascript? You can build xls files with JS too!

Comment: My JS isn't perfect but it's better than my C#. I don't think you understand though, I'm using a C# controller because I'm using the backoffice of Umbraco, so I'm using an angular app with a C# controller to do this. I don't know if I can set the Angular.js to perform this without the C# controller?

Comment: I know, I've seen that stack before. You can just return in any shape/form, the data (from Umbraco) that you want from C#'s controller, and then use JS to create an xls/xlsx file, and save it to the user's machine with [this library](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls).

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more :|

Comment: No worries, I ended up solving it with Angular only, I don't know why I thought I needed a C# controller to do the work when Angular can do the same thing. Now for the next part, I need to figure out how to import data